# Fastest way to convert files into lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a .txt file which contains some words:
e.g

```
bye

bicycle

bi
cyc
le
```

and i want to return a list which contains all the words in the file. I have tried some code which actually works but i think it takes a lot of time to execute for bigger files. Is there a way to make this code more efficient?

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line == '\n': --> #blank line 
            lst1.append(line)
        else:
            lst1.append(line.replace('\n', '')) --> #the way i find more efficient to concatenate letters of a specific word
    str1 = ''.join(lst1)
    lst_fin = str1.split()
```

expected output:

```
lst_fin = ['bye', 'bicycle', 'bicycle']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is more efficient, but at least it's an alternative... :)

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    words = f.read().replace('\n\n', '|').replace('\n', '').split('|')
print(words)
```

...or if you don't want to insert a character like `'|'` (which could be already there) into the data you could do also

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    words = f.read().split('\n\n')
    words = [w.replace('\n', '') for w in words]
print(words)
```

---

result is the same in both cases:

```
# ['bye', 'bicycle', 'bicycle']
```

---

***EDIT:***

I think I have another approach. However, it requires the file *not to start* with a blank line, iiuc...

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    res = []
    current_elmnt = next(f).strip()
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():
            current_elmnt += line.strip()
        else:
            res.append(current_elmnt)
            current_elmnt = ''
print(words)
```

Perhaps you want to give it a try...

Comment: tried your code on a bigger file (list with 650000 elts), it saves me 0.03s compared to my code, not bad tho ahah

Comment: Perfect, you're welcome. Have fun with this saved time! :)

Comment: Hmm, ok, was worth a try... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `iter` function with a sentinel of `''` instead:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    lst_fin = list(iter(lambda: ''.join(iter(map(str.strip, f).__next__, '')), ''))
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/TalkativeCostlyUpgrades

Comment: lovely. quite hard to understand but lovely.

Comment: Your comment about memory usage and efficiency is true for the first two approaches I proposed, but is also the reason why I added a third one, which also iterates over the file line by line.

Comment: @SpghttCd Ah I did not notice you added a third approach. Removed my comment then.

Comment: I left the first two because in timing tests they were the fastest. However, I doubt that timings made by use of StringIO objects are realistic - perhaps the only reasonable way here is to let OP check the timings with their actual data...

Comment: @SpghttCd Yes, reading the entire file into memory is only inefficient when dealing with a file so large that it causes the program to start using the swap memory.

Comment: That means on the other handside (besides this constraint) IMO iiuc that it almost doesn't matter which approach they choose, because the main time is needed for IO. There won't be a real jump forward in efficiency just because of the algorithm how the right words are concatenated because the main load here is to read all the data in...

Comment: @SpghttCd My point is that in the event that the file is so large that the returning value of `f.read()` plus the output list occupy more memory than the size of the physical RAM and make the program use the much slower filesystem-based swap memory, then `f.read()` will become a bottleneck.

Comment: Completely agree - and I just wanted to state that as long as we focus on all other algorithms (or really know that `read()`+ `list` fit into memory...), i.e. those which iterate over the file, we imo will not see relevant differences in performance, as the timing depends on IO, not on the algorithm which puzzles the data together.

Comment: Or in other words to come back to answer the title question "Fastest way to convert files into lists?": _A: Buy a faster harddisk._

Answer (score 0):

You could use this(I don't know about its efficiency):

```py
lst = []
s = ''
with open('tp.txt', 'r') as file:
    l = file.readlines()
    for i in l:
        if i == '\n':
            lst.append(s)
            s = ''
        elif i == l[-1]:
            s += i.rstrip()
            lst.append(s)
        else:
            s+= i.rstrip()
print(lst)
```

Comment: i think this is a bit less efficient than mine, it has a more complex syntax

Comment: Sorry... as I said, I don't know about efficiency. Anyways I think you got your answer(by SpghttCd)